# Typescript typing http headers

Tags: typescript, express, header, apollo-server

I've got very confused about *Typescript* and its type definitions suggestions. I'm doing a Graphql API with *Apollo Server* and trying to implement authorization with JWT through request headers (I'm rewritting an existing API), so first I'm extracting token from request headers doing:

```js
const token: string = req.headers.authorization
```

But doing that throws an error saying "type ***string* | *undefined*** is not assignable to type ***string***" so I changed it to:

```js
const token: string | undefined = req.headers.authorization
```

All right! But in the original API they tries to get authorization prop from `req.headers.authorization` or `req.headers.Authorization`, I don't know why but I tried to do the same doing:

```js
const token: string | undefined = req.headers.authorization || req.headers.Authorization
```

And got a new error: "type ***string* | *string[]* | *undefined*** is not assignable to type ***string* | *undefined***"

Then I changed it again to:

```js
const token: string | undefined | string[] = req.headers.authorization || req.headers.Authorization
```

My questions:

- Why `req.headers.authorization` and `req.headers.Authorization` has different data types?
- I Google it and all tutorials about authorization uses `req.headers.authorization`, so what about `req.headers.Authorization`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1: Why req.headers.authorization and req.headers.Authorization has different data types?

Your answer lies [here, in the TypeScript definitions for node's http library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/http.d.ts).

As you can see, `req.headers.authorization` is defined like this:

```js
'authorization'?: string;
```

Because it's optional, it can be `undefined`. Otherwise, it's a `string`.

Now look for where `req.headers.Authorization` would be defined. Spoiler alert, you won't find it on the list. That means you have to look back up to the type definition for `req.headers`:

```js
interface IncomingHttpHeaders extends NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]> {
  ...other stuff
}
```

Which means that for any string not defined in "other stuff", the type can be `undefined`, `string`, or `string[]`.

#### 2: I Google it and all tutorials about authorization uses req.headers.authorization, so what about req.headers.Authorization?

According to the HTTP Spec, headers are actually case-insensitive. Things like express (and by extension ApolloServer, which runs on express) lowercase them for you by default, so you should generally use `req.headers.authorization`.

#### Bonus

If you ever use `apollo-server-lambda`, for some reason (maybe for AWS reasons?) the capitalization is maintained, so you have to use `event.headers.Authorization`. That means that if you're going to do something in a generic space that can swap between different ApolloServer implementations, you're going to be better off looking in both places, accepting `undefined | string | string[]`, and then checking to see if it's an array and using the first element.

#### Unrelated [hopefully helpful] Semantics

```
const token: string | undefined | string[] = req.headers.authorization || req.headers.Authorization
```

The variable name `token` *technically* shouldn't be accurate. The authorization header is supposed to be `Authorization: <type> <credentials>`. If you're looking for a "token", it's probably in the header, after the word `Bearer` . Not everybody follows that, but you can usually split on the space and take the last piece, unless you really do want the whole header, in which case, ignore this bit.